# energy efficiency, transformation from chemical to thermal energy, for district heating plants

Tags: energy, heat

If I have a system in which I introduce $\mathrm{100~e.u.F}$ (energy units) derived from chemical energy (i.e. fuel) and generate thermal energy to heat water what are e.u. absorbed by water? I.e. the efficiency of the transformation?

Basically I would like to know the "average/general" efficiency of energy transformation for a district heating plant. Considered that the only energy input is fuel and the only energy output is heat (no electricity)?

What are the energy loss?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Usually we are concerned with the efficiency of converting chemical energy to work, with the loss being heat.